# React-Native How to use a Boolean

Tags: javascript, react-native, boolean

I don't know how to work with a Boolean in React-Native.

I tried to find a solution on google but apparently my question is so simple that no-one has asked it.

**Whereat my code do I have to declare the boolean?

How can I change the value?**

What is the right way to compare it? (I think if(myBoolean===true) but I am not completely sure.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a JS question than an React Native one, since React Native uses standard-compliant JavaScript as programming language. So, going through all your questions:

> Where in my code do I have to declare the boolean?

The boolean is one of the 6 data type primitives in JS, along with null, undefined, number, string and Symbol (ES6 only). So you can just create a boolean the way you would with any of those. For instance:

```
var myBoolean = true;
```

You can create the boolean in pretty much any part of your code: inside a function, as a global variable, as an object property...

Remember than JS is a dynamically weakly typed language, which means that if you assign a different type value to `myBoolean`, it would then be of that type. For instance:

```
var myBoolean = true; // I'm a boolean
myBoolean = "A string"; // I'm a string
```

> How can I change the value?

We just changed its value by initializing the variable, but it would be as simple as:

```
var myBoolean = true; // I'm a boolean
myBoolean = false;
```

> What is the right way to compare it ? (I think if(myBoolean===true) but I am not completely sure.)

Your approach is totally correct, but you can also do some other things in this case. This are all valid:

```
if(myBoolean === true) // Will check that myBoolean has the same value and type as true 
if(myBoolean == true) // Will check that myBoolean has the same value as true
if(myBoolean) // Will check that myBoolean has a 'truthy' value (anything that is not a false, 0, "", null, undefined or NaN (not a number).
```

Answer (score 2):

martinarroyo's answer is fantastic, but just to add:

React Native uses **JSX** (XML + JavaScript).

When using **JSX**, always encapsulate booleans in curly braces:

```
<View>
  <MapView
    showsUserLocation={true}
  >
  </Mapview>
</View>
```

You can also do some interesting things with **JSX**, like conditionally render components:

```
<View>
  // This component will render
  <TouchableHighlight>
    {true}
  </TouchableHighlight>
  // This component will not render
  <TouchableHighlight>
    {false}
  </TouchableHighlight>
</View>
```

More information here:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html